# IPhone 4 Transfering Pictures

Tags: backup

I am upgrading my phone from the 4 to the 6 and trying to back up all photos and videos and everytime I move a photo from the Camera Roll to the Photo Stream to upload to the Cloud and the erase from the Roll it also erases the same picture from the photo stream.
It defeats the whole purpose...Help !

Answer (score 1):

When, upgrading, I always just backup my old iPhone to iTunes and restore the iTunes backup.  That gets all pics including the camera roll.

I just recently upgraded from a 5s to 6, and I still have the very first pic I took with an iPhone on July 11, 2008 and that is how I've always done it.

Note: backup in iTunes is not the same as syncing with iTunes.  Click the phone icon to find the backup button.

Comment: +1 Personally, I always Sync first, then Backup - then do whatever else... update iOS/add new phone etc. then backup again when done. Belt & braces ;)  Also - use Encrypted Backup - that way you also save your passwords to the new phone

Comment: True, I always sync first too, but that's what happens when you plug the cable in, then you go find backup/restore. Surprisingly many people don't realize there is a difference.

Comment: Does it sync by default? Must be so long since I switched that off, I'd forgotten it was even an option ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin mine does, probably a setting to turn it off, I actually RARELY backup or sync with a cable anymore. Getting a new phone is about the only time because it's faster, otherwise I use wifi sync and iCloud backup.  Getting a new device tho calls for the full BACKUP of the old device via cable, followed by restore on the new device via the cable.